# Problem getting resources after building a .jar

Tags: java

If you run the application from the idea, everything works correctly, it finds the resources.
If I make an artifact **.jar**, there is an error.
All files are present, what's the problem?

```
fs = new FileInputStream(Shader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(sourceVertex).getFile().replaceFirst("/", ""));
sourceVertex = new String(fs.readAllBytes());
```

**java.exe -jar OpenGL.jar**
OUT:

```
java.io.FileNo tFoundException:file:E:\IdeaProjects\MYPROJECTS\OpenGL\out\artifacts\OpenGL_jar\OpenGL.jar!\engine\vs.glsl
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.render.Shader.init(Shader.java:29)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.render.Shader.<init>(Shader.java:23)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.render.Engine.init(Engine.java:65)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.render.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:55)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.boot.Application.main(Application.java:11)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.render.Shader.init(Shader.java:37)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.render.Shader.<init>(Shader.java:23)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.render.Engine.init(Engine.java:65)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.render.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:55)
        at en.toshaessential.timusengine.boot.Application.main(Application.java:11)
```

I also noticed that when I search for files I search in **OpenGL.jar!** and not in **OpenGL.jar**. Why so?

I wanted to build a .jar application and run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileInputStream` works on files. Separately that's not how you deal with resources, and that's not how you read files in, and this isn't how to use `getResource`. Here's how to do it right:

```
String sourceVertex = "foo.png"; // if foo.png is in the same dir as shader class
String sourceVertex = "/imgs/foo.png"; // if it's in a dir named 'imgs' in the root of the jar

try (var in = Shader.class.getResourceAsStream(sourceVertex)) {
  sourceVertex = new String(in.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

This:

- Uses try-with to avoid the memory leak.
- Avoids the strictly inferior `getClassLoader()` - that fails in exotic circumstances and is needless typing.
- avoids `FileInputStream`, which doesn't work except on literally files.
- Sets charset encoding, which you should always do (or, target java17+ only with `--release 17`, where UTF_8 is now the default).